# How to rename label on radio button using jquery

Tags: jquery, radio-button, label, radio-group, renaming

Hi i have  the following

```
<label>
    <INPUT style="DISPLAY: inline; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle" class=fieldValue  name=radioOpt    value=1 CHECKED type=radio>&nbsp;Option1
</label>
<label>
    <INPUT style="DISPLAY: inline; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle" class=fieldValue  name=radioOpt    value=2 CHECKED type=radio>&nbsp;Option2
</label>
<label>
    <INPUT style="DISPLAY: inline; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle" class=fieldValue  name=radioOpt    value=3 CHECKED type=radio>&nbsp;Option3
</label>
```

I want to rename option x to test x base on some event.

```
var radioOpt = $("input[name=radioOpt][value=1]");
```

would give me radio button. How would i rename its label?

Comment: Your `input` should not be nested inside the `label` element.

Comment: the radio option are generated from a tag library.

Comment: That's too bad, because that's bad markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont want to change the markup, You can do the following to Change that text for this case

```
$(function(){
     $("input[name=radioOpt][value=1]")
      .parent()
      .contents()
      .last()[0].nodeValue = 'Test 1';
});
```

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/U7TMs/

Comment: is this faster than.
[code]
    var radioOpt = $("input[name=radioOpt][value=1]");  
    var radioLabel = radioOpt.parent();
    radioLabel.html(radioOpt).text(" Test 1");
[/code]

Comment: @user578635, I am not exactly sure, but the one in my code doesn't have any extra operations. Use the one you feel comfortable with. The speed difference for this case will be negligible if any I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try like below,

```
$(function () {
    $("input[name=radioOpt]").parent().contents().each(function () {
        if (this.nodeType == 3 && this.nodeValue.indexOf('Option') != -1) {
            this.nodeValue = 'Test';
        }
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Cgv2f/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following:

```
var labelForOpt = radioOpt.parent();
```

However the `label` should, for accessibility reasons, have `for` attribute, to specify to which `input` it 'belongs', for example:

```
<label for="radioElement1">For radio One:</label>
<input id="radioElement1" />
```

This means that you don't have to nest the `input` within the `label`, and clicking the `label` will trigger a click on the associated `input`.

It's also worth pointing out that your HTML is invalid:

```
<label>
    <INPUT style="DISPLAY: inline; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle" class=fieldValue ) name=radioOpt value=1 CHECKED type=radio>&nbsp;Option1
</label>
```

There shouldn't be a floating `)` inside of the HTML for the `input` element.

Comment: Actually, it **is** valid to place an `input` inside a `label`. By doing this, the `label` is *implicitly* associated with the nested `input`, without the need of `for` and `id` attributes. From the [W3C HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1): "To associate a label with another control implicitly, the control element must be within the contents of the `LABEL` element. In this case, the `LABEL` may only contain one control element. The label itself may be positioned before or after the associated control."

Comment: Ah, that was perhaps an error poor description, or phrasing? The invalid portion was the floating parenthesis in the HTML; the nesting of an `input` within its `label` is, of course, fine.

Comment: I was referring to your statement that the `label` should have a `for` attribute to explicitly associate it with the `input`. This is not necessary when the `input` is nested in the `label`, in that case the association is created implicitly.

Comment: Oh; that. In which case, you're right, yes: the `for` isn't required in that circumstance.

Comment: thanks i realize my markup error. I can't change the html markup since its generated from tag library.

Answer (score 0):

```
radioOpt.closest("label");
```

This will give you the closest `label` element which is an ancestor of the selected element (or the element itself, but this is not the case). You can then replace the text using `.html(function)` or by iterating over `.contents()`, filtering the text nodes (where [`this.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType)`=== 3`) and replacing the value.

Unrelated with your actual question, but I'd like to inform you that there are quite a few markup errors in your HTML. There shouldn't be a `)` after the `class` attribute, you can't check more than one radio button with the same name and it's a bad idea to use inline styling when you can use a class to style them with CSS.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioOpt" class="fieldValue" value="1" checked/> Option1
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioOpt" class="fieldValue" value="2"/> Option2
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioOpt" class="fieldValue" value="3"/> Option3
</label>
```

Then, put the styling in a CSS stylesheet:

```
input.fieldValue {
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**HTML** :

```
    <INPUT style="DISPLAY: inline; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle" class=fieldValue ) name=radioOpt    value=1 CHECKED type=radio id="op1"><label for = "op1">Option1
</label>
<label>
    <INPUT style="DISPLAY: inline; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle" class="fieldValue" name="radioOpt" id="op2"   value="2" CHECKED type="radio"><label for = "op2">Option2
</label>
<label>
    <INPUT id="op3" style="DISPLAY: inline; VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle" class=fieldValue ) name=radioOpt    value=3 CHECKED type=radio><label for = "op3" >Option3

</label>​
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("input[name=radioOpt]").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('label[for='+id+']').text('test_'+$(this).attr('value'));
});
​
```

Here is the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3UFJw/1/)